# raise attention?

Tags: phrase-usage, collocations

Is the following use of "raise attention from" natural? How does it differ from "raise the attention of"?

> The client's unfortunate experience, which has **raised attention from** our IT experts, points to an error in our database.

(I made this up myself. Maybe "drawn" should be used instead?)

Comment: I'll ask the same question I invariably ask: **Where did you find this?** It makes a big difference. If it's a quote from an interview, it might be a simple slip-up of the tongue. If it's from a written article, I'd love to read the surrounding text. If you're writing it yourself, well, we should have the benefit of knowing that.

Comment: I made it up myself. Maybe "drawn" should be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

You're conflating uses with **raised ... from**.

**attention** can be understood as the state of an attender, as a result produced by that which raises the attention of the attender, or as a thing unto itself.

**Raised...attention**, as a transitive construction, refers to an effect produced *in the attender*.  For that reason, **from** is inappropriate.

> The patient received the doctor's attention.
>
> The patient received the attention of the doctor.
>
> The patient received attention *from* the doctor.
>
> The strange symptom quickly raised the doctor's attention.

Comment: Your last example can be paraphrased as "The strange symptom quickly raised concern from the doctor," can't it?

Comment: I'm sure many native speakers would find nothing wrong with your paraphrase, but "raise {something} **from** {someone}" is not a viable construction when the {something}  *inheres* in the {someone}. We don't say "raised doubt *from* them"

Comment: How about "raised the concern of the doctor"?

Comment: That would be idiomatic, **of** being the periphrastic possessive.